# How to restrict zoom min and max ranges in python holoviews?

Tags: python, zooming, holoviews

I am using holoviews to display a RGB picture using the command below (stack[1] being the image I want to display):

```py
pix = hv.RGB(stack[1]).opts(
    xaxis=None, 
    yaxis=None,
    tools=['wheel_zoom','pan'],
    default_tools=[],
    active_tools=['wheel_zoom','pan']
)
```

It displays fine but when I use the wheel zoom, I can zoom out way past the limits of my image. Is there a way to restrict the limits of my plot so it never goes past the boundaries of my data/image?

Comment: I found this github issue: https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/1019 Hope someone else can help you on this one. Maybe its possible to use some bokeh on your plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there is an option but you can use an hook for this

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
def bounds_hook(plot, elem, xbounds=None, ybounds=None):
    x_range = plot.handles['plot'].x_range
    y_range = plot.handles['plot'].y_range
    if xbounds is not None:
        x_range.bounds = xbounds
    else:
        x_range.bounds = x_range.start, x_range.end 
    if ybounds is not None:
        y_range.bounds = ybounds
    else:
        y_range.bounds = y_range.start, y_range.end 
(hv.Image(np.random.rand(100,100)).opts(hooks=[bounds_hook]) +
hv.Image(np.random.rand(100,100)).opts(hooks=[partial(bounds_hook, xbounds=(-1, 1), ybounds=(-1,1))], axiswise=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def plot_limits(plot, element):
             plot.handles['x_range'].min_interval = 100
             plot.handles['x_range'].max_interval = 5500000
             plot.handles['y_range'].min_interval = 500
             plot.handles['y_range'].max_interval = 900000
 hv.Image(np.random.rand(100,100)).opts=hooks=[plot_limits]
```